# Remove 'X' from vim tab bar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

When using multiple tabs in `vim`, there is a bar at the top displaying the tabs. At the far right of that bar there is an `X`. This is used to close the current tab if use of the mouse is enabled; however, I don't use the mouse in vim, so for me it is a bit of useless cruft taking up space.

With many tabs open, vim doesn't display the whole filename in each files, only the last few characters. Getting rid of this `X` -- and the small amount of empty space that seems to be reserved next to it -- would free up a little bit of space. I would be interested in a method to simply turn it invisible, but the ideal answer would give me a way to remove it entirely and free up this space.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @DanielBeck Oh, sorry: Linux (Ubuntu 13.04), but I don't think that should matter since this is a internal thing to vim. The tab bar runs within the terminal window that I call vim in, it's not a function of the operating system's window manager or anything like that.

Comment: You are trying to save one character (that's all the `X` takes) in order to accomodate an inherently broken system. Not only saving only one character obviously won't help getting more readable tab names but tabs, in and off themselves are a very poor way to work with multiple buffers in Vim. Anyway, did you read `:help setting-tabline`?

Comment: Try working with [buffers](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ) instead of tabs.

Answer (score 1):

> The 'tabline' option allows you to define your preferred way to tab pages
>   labels.  This isn't easy, thus an example will be given here.

You'll find an example (that you can modify to exclude the `X` character) at `:help setting-tabline`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the default Vim tabline is hardcoded in C and the X is defined there, as you can see in [`src/nvim/screen.c`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/e6beb60da517b6d7d7461687bf91f87d097b9563/src/nvim/screen.c#L7125) file.

The solution would be to recreate Vim's default tabline (or something close to it) using the syntax of the 'tabline' variable, and omit the X in there. 
You can find several possible implementations in the comments [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_tab_number_in_your_tab_line).